# xgettext to generate po file from html files

Tags: html, internationalization, gettext, xgettext

This is something I am trying so hard to get. tried a bunch of options, including this one found here [Extracting gettext strings from Javascript and HTML files (templates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026651/extracting-gettext-strings-from-javascript-and-html-files-templates). No go.

this is the sample html

```
<h1 data-bind="text: _loc('translate this')"></h1>
```

the command I have tried (php, glade..)

```
xgettext -LPHP --force-po -o E:\Samples\poEdit\translated.po --from-code=utf-8 -k_loc E:\Samples\poEdit\html\samplePO.html
```

glade seems to look only inside tags and completely skips the keyword. Anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually ended up writing a small .net application to parse the html and create a json representation and used language PYTHON with xgettext to create the po file from javascript.